# Audit trail that create a record of the old and new data

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-express, audit-trail

I have these tables that need to record all of the data changes from `INSERT` `UPDATE` and `DELETE` operation.

I found a [Blogpost](https://www.sqlshack.com/various-techniques-to-audit-sql-server-databases/) about techniques in auditing sql. so I tried following the instruction.

This is my Audit specification:

[image]

And this was the output:

[image]

The record was great but It does not capture the value before and after it was changed. Is there a way to configure that out?

Now I'm trying to read CDC/Temporal Tables

Also 11,000 data was expected to be put on the table.

Comment: That link discusses different ways of "auditing". The specific technique you tried is noted as not providing "what actually changes". Your test proves that, does it not? So pick one of the others that matches your needs.

Comment: I think you'll find that CDC matches your expectation more.

Comment: @BenThul CDC SQL Express does not have CDC

Comment: Whelp... rolling your own with triggers is probably what is going to take then.